# JXDatePicker questions (Part 1)

Tags: java, swingx

I want to use JXDatePicker in my project. I am first time to learn swingx. My questions is:

(1) How to clear the "Today is [today date]"?

(2) How to show the current date in dd-MM-YYYY before I click the datepicker choose calendar?

(3) How to change the icon of the button?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) How to clear the "Today is [today date]"?

Use `JXDatePicker#setLinkPanel` and supply what ever you want...

> (2) How to show the current date in dd-MM-YYYY before I click the datepicker choose calendar?

Use `JXDatePicker#setFormats`

> (3) How to change the icon of the button?

You can change the popup buttons icon using something like `UIManager.put("JXDatePicker.arrowIcon", icon)`.  The look and feel expects an `Icon`

This is a global change, all instance of `JXDatePicker` will pick it.  You could instantiate a custom `BasicDatePickerUI` and override it's `createPopupButton` method to return create the `JButton` yourself.  This would allow you to customise a single instance of `JXDatePicker`